# What are the problems with using a predictor with a low base rate in a GLM?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, rare-events

A reviewer has questioned my use of a dummy coded predictor that has a low base rate of occurrence. Specifically, they question how well my conclusions would generalize given that the event occurs rarely. I am unsure how to address this, since I am not clear on exactly why or when this is an issue in a GLM and am hoping the community may be able to provide some clarity on this.

**My Model**

$y_i = \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_0$,

where both x_2 and x_1 are dummy coded variables (0 or 1). x_2 has an occurrence rate of about 8% while x_1 has an occurrence rate of about 17%.

My hypothesis tests are a simple t-test of whether each predictor is significantly different from 0.

**My Questions**

1. Why exactly is a low base rate a problem? Is this an issue in model estimation or in the hypothesis test?
2. How rare does an event have to be for this to be an issue? Are both my predictors problematic? Is there a rule of thumb for this?
3. How might other aspects of the model like sample size or the rate of co-occurrence of each event change how problematic rare events are?
4. Are there other ways to include rare events like this in a model that are less susceptible to these problems?